# Mass ?query= dumped in to server requests

Tags: url, url-parameters

At some point in the past few months almost all of the URLs in the logs starting containing this:

***?query=***

I tried using all of the major search engines (Bing, Google, Yahoo and Yandex) however even with the quote operator I couldn't find anything.

I've made no changes to the server let alone to the configuration.

My best guess is that this likely has something to do with cPanel though I can't confirm since I don't know what I'd be looking for. The slightest chance it could be some really odd off-beat update to PHP though they don't seem to screw things up like that.

I've checked:

- `.htaccess`, no changes.
- PHP code, no instances of `$_GET['query']` or `query=`.
- Search engines fail to honor `"?query="` query.
- No changes to `robots.txt`.
- The cPanel forums are active though their login page redirects and even after loading still fails; no idea what I'd post there if I could authenticate.

It could be an external issue, Google has been acting really wonky suddenly having issues but no issues or anything invalid with the robots.txt file.

Suggestions please?